# Apache Wicket Reset View from Model

Tags: java, wicket-6

I want to reset the filter settings on a datagrid through an onClickEvent. Is it possible to clear the filters without having to resort to javascript?

I currently set the filter in the underlying dataprovider to null and then set the responsePage to the current page:

```
setResponsePage(getPage());
```

While this refreshes the datagrid itself without filters, the values in the filter textboxes are still present. The filters are in a topToolBar which is attached to the datagrid component.

Comment: How do you populate the models for the filter input fields ? Do they use the same `Filter` object that you have reset in the DataProvider ? Please show us more code.

Comment: The Filter object is reused yes. This was the core of the problem since the values in the filter weren't being reinitialized.
I've solved it by creating a completely new instance of the page by calling setResponsePage(getPage().getClass()).